# Oliver FTP Directory Listing

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Has anyone used Oliver Simple FTP before? http://oliver.sourceforge.net/

I've set everything up, managed to log in with my newly created ftp account.  However, there is no directory listing.  When I log in via filezilla for example, this does infact show.  Anyone had a similar problem? Can't find any docs on this.. Cheers!

Edit>

I've turned on all global variables in the config settings. When I log in, the syslog tells me:

```
oliver[29402]: OK: Logged in: user=ftpuser
```

But when I try to upload a file - nothing happens. Create a directory works! As I can see this via filezilla, but still no listing on OliverFTP.  Also, there are no syslog's with this activity, so I'm not sure how to debug.

Edit>
Found the answer:

```
$conf['ftp_passive'] = false;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In your *config.php*, do you have `$conf['enable_logging'] = true;`?
What does it say in your syslog when you log in?

Comment: Yes, this is enabled - I've updated my Question, if you have come accross a similar problem before.  I'm using vsftpd by the way.

Comment: Check your webserver (apache, nginx, etc.) logs for permission errors. Also, make sure that the permissions on the ftp_cache folder allow the web server to write to it.

Comment: Cheers for your help - setting the ftp_passive to false sorted it!